# How to play video without AVPlayer or Movie Player on iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, video, opengl-es

I need to play custom format video on iOS, with all the rendering done by myself.

My current choice is OpenGL ES, but it takes too much CPU from profiling result (mostly in glTexImage2D).

Is there any faster alternatives for my need?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using `glTexImage2D()` for texture creation only, or for each frame?

Comment: I doubt that the display of video to the screen via OpenGL ES is your limiting factor here.  In a video processing application, I was able to capture from the iPhone 4 camera and feed that back to the screen at an easy 60 FPS: http://www.sunsetlakesoftware.com/2010/10/22/gpu-accelerated-video-processing-mac-and-ios .  Your bottleneck has to be somewhere else, most likely in your decoding routines.

Comment: @genpfault I use glTexImage2D for each frame, as that's the way I know to draw the image to screen. I'm quite new to OpengGL

Comment: @Brad I'm reading your color tracking sample code. It seems you also used glTexImage2D within the processNewCameraFrame method. Maybe I did some wrong setting. I'll try to profile your code to find out the difference. Just out of curiosity, why the AVPlayer runs so fast? It doesn't use OpenGL at all (observed from OpengGL instrument)

Answer (score 0):

AVPlayer is going to be fast because the code has been optimized to decompress using GPU acceleration and llvm optimizations.  If you want to use OpenGL ES, you will probably end up using EAGLContext, creating texture shaders and doing other low-level optimizations.  Our app can composite multiple layers on top of video at a high frame rate with very low CPU load.

Comment: But AVPlayer can't handle the format my video compressed as. It sees this class is solely for standard file or streaming playback

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can use openmax application layer integration using egl which will stream the video to opengl es 2.0 via egl and can be stored  or displayed to opengl es screen. Can help you if i can have the snippet :)